# Shaded pole speed control with PWM

Tags: switching, motor-controller

I have a fan with a shaded pole motor and I installed [this PWM for speed control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LODGP2E).

At the moment everything is working well, speed adjustment is sensitive and the fan is barely moving at about the 60% range of the knob adjustment.

Do I risk damaging the motor with this setup?  Should I have gone with a different speed control method like a triac or variac?

Comment: It is extremely probable that the control speed device you purchased, advertised  as a PWM control, is in reality a TRIAC partialization control: on the board, I see too few components for a PWM generator, and instead I see what seems to be a DIAC (the blue diode-like device near the blue trimmer) and a TRIAC mounted on the heat sink. However, this will surely not damage your fan motor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not surprising that a variable voltage speed controller does not work very well with a shaded pole motor. At full voltage, peak torque is likely only a little higher than the full-speed running torque. The motor is not very efficient at full voltage, so the losses when the motor is stalled at reduced voltage may not be much different from the losses under normal operation. However, there is no air moving over the motor when it is stalled or running at a very low speed. The motor temperature may rise above the safe limit, that will certainly shorten the motor's life, but probably not cause it to fail very quickly.

A different voltage control method will not help at all. A variable frequency control should work reasonably well, but there are likely none available for a motor like that at a reasonable price.